# Bootstrap a large data set

Tags: r

I would like to bootstrap a large data set which contains multiple column and row variables.  The following is a simplified re-creation of my data set:

```
charDataDiff <- data.frame(c('A','B','C'), matrix(1:72, nrow=9))
colnames(charDataDiff) <- c("patchId","s380","s390","s400","s410","s420","s430","s440","s450")
```

Separate the data using the `patchId` as the criteria. This creates three lists: one for each Variable

```
idColor <-  c("A", "B", "C")
(patchSpectrum <- lapply(idColor, function(idColor) charDataDiff[charDataDiff$patchId==idColor,]))
```

Created the function `sampleBoot` to sample the `patchSpectrum`

```
sampleBoot <-  function(nbootstrap=2, patch=3){
    return(lapply(1:nbootstrap, function(i)
             {patchSpectrum[[patch]][sample(1:nrow(patchSpectrum[[patch]]),replace=TRUE),]}))}
```

Example:

```
sampleBoot(5,3)
```

Here is where I am stuck:

1. I need to sample each `patchId` list along with each column variable (which the above "sampleBoot" easily accomplish),
2. Take the median of each `patchId` sampling list iteration, and
3. Create a new population of the medians to calculate parametric parameters. I can do it manually but that would be silly.

Comment: I don't know why you did not define data<-1:72 ?

Comment: Your separation step can be written more simply as `patchSpectrum <- by(charDataDiff, charDataDiff$varNames, data.frame)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I understand from your question, you may do as follows:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(sampleBoot(5, 3), function(x) apply(x[-1], 2, median)))
```

It crates a table of the medians of 5 samplings of patch 3.

Comment: Thank you i will re-post the issue with more clarity. your answer helped me re-define the issue.

Comment: @RagyIsaac So the command above is not what you desired? It creates a table of population medians I think